# Notation for the space of product measures on $\mathbb{R}^n$

Tags: measure-theory

Let $\mathcal{M}(\mathbb{R}^n)$ be the set of measures on the probability space $(\mathbb{R}^n,\mathcal{B}(\mathbb{R}^n))$. I am interested in the subset of this set corresponding to the set of all product measures: that is, measures $\mu$ such that $\mu=\otimes_{i=1}^n\mu_i$, where each $\mu_i$ is a measure on $(\mathbb{R},\mathcal{B}(\mathbb{R}))$.

I believe this is a proper subset of $\mathcal{M}(\mathbb{R}^n)$, as in general for measures $\mu,\nu$ on $(\mathbb{R},\mathcal{B}(\mathbb{R}))$, there may be many couplings with marginals $\mu$, $\nu$, but only the independent coupling would be in this set.

Has this concept been used in literature anywhere, and is there a standard notation for this set?

If there is not a standard notation, would $\Pi_{i=1}^n\mathcal{M}(\mathbb{R})$ or $\bigotimes_{i=1}^n\mathcal{M}(\mathbb{R})$ be more accurate to describe this set?